# Method does not get invoked

Tags: c#, events, delegates, invoke

I'm writing code for Windows application in c#,I have 2 Class, 1 is GUI class where I declare events and delegates for ShowLog() method.The next class which is like a back end class, where I have all methods definition which are going to calls from GUI class. My problem is I want to access the some GUI class methods from the back end class using delegates and events. So How to do it.

```
   namespace Linux_ScriptRunner
  {
  public delegate void MyDel(object str);   
 public partial class LinuxScriptRunner : Form
   {
     public event MyDel MyEvent; 

    public void pqr(object str)
    {

        MyEvent(str);
    }




  private void btnSendCommand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstcmd =txtBxCmdLine.Text;           
        if (!lstcmd_list.Contains(lstcmd))
            lstcmd_list.Add(txtBxCmdLine.Text);
        else
        {
            lstcmd_list.Remove(lstcmd);
            lstcmd_list.Add(lstcmd);
        }
        count++;            
        lstcmdbtn.Enabled = true;            
        try
        {
            isButtonEnable = false;
            EnableDishableButton();
            string serverIPS = string.Empty;
            ListView.SelectedIndexCollection indexes= this.lstVwServerList.SelectedIndices;
            foreach (int index in indexes)
                serverIPS += "||" + lstVwServerList.Items[index].Text;

            if (serverIPS != "")
            {                 

                    System.Threading.Thread th = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(myButtonExcutionForCommand));
                    th.IsBackground = true;
                    th.Start(txtBxCmdLine.Text.Trim() + serverIPS);
                    lstLastAct.Items.Add(" => " + txtBxCmdLine.Text + " on " + serverIPS);
                    txtBxCmdLine.Text = String.Empty;
                    this.lstVwServerList.SelectedItems.Clear();
             //   txtBxCmdLine.Text = String.Empty;
               // this.lstVwServerList.SelectedItems.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select Ip for IP List \n ");
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Program.WriteExceptionLog(ex);
        }

    }




public void ShowLog(object s1)
    {
        string status = ((string)s1);
        try
        {
            if (richtxtBxResult.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action<string>(ShowLog), status);                  
            }                
            else
            {                      
                richtxtBxResult.Text += Environment.NewLine + status;
                richtxtBxResult.SelectionStart = richtxtBxResult.Text.Length;
                richtxtBxResult.ScrollToCaret();
                richtxtBxResult.Refresh();                   

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Program.WriteExceptionLog(ex);
        }
    }





 private void myButtonExcutionForCommand(object commandAndServerIPS)
    {            
            try
            {
                string[] sep = {"||"};
                string[] temp = ((string)commandAndServerIPS).Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
               int i = 1;
               while (i < temp.Count())
                {

                    ShowLog(temp[0] + " is executing for " + temp[i]);
                    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Command Executing ... ";
                 script_runner.ExcuteCommand(temp[i], temp[0]," ");                     
                   //ShowLog("");
                  toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = " command executed Successfully... ";
                    i++;
                // ShowLog(temp[i]);
                 ShowLog("\n\n -*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*- \n\n");

               }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Fill Column Name !!!");
               //richtxtBxResult.Text = "Im here exception_mybuttonec";
                ShowLog(ex.Message);
                Program.WriteExceptionLog(ex);
            }
            isButtonEnable = true;
            EnableDishableButton();           

    }   


    }
    }

    }



 2nd file class.......


    namespace LinuxScriptRunner
    {

  class scriptRunner
        {

      public string ExcuteCommand(String serIp, string cmd,string serDet)
      {      
        int port;
        string un=String.Empty;
        string pwd=string.Empty;
        string os=String.Empty;


        LinuxScriptRunner lsr = new LinuxScriptRunner();
       lsr.MyEvent += new MyDel(lsr.ShowLog);
   System.Threading.Thread th1 = new System.Threading.Thread(new             System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(lsr.pqr));
      th1.IsBackground = true;
       th1.Start("hi"); 




    }
    }
```

Here in code the Class LinuxSriptRunner which is my GUI class have the event and delegate and I want to access the event from class b using GUI class event. 
I hope You got my points

Comment: Could you please describe your problem in a bit more detail or at least in other words; as written now it is impossible to understand. Also, your code does not even compile.

Comment: Yes, So what is my object that....I have a GUI class and a other class which is having the methods to do functioning from GUI class.now the task is Access the methods of GUI class form the other class. using Delegates and events.where Delegates and event define in GUI class and those delegates. & event use in other class to access the GUI class methods. I hope you got my point

Comment: In above code I declare a Delegates MyDelegate for ShowLog() method and declare a event Myevent to fire on ShowLog() into GUI class..ShowLog(), method declare in GUI class ..and I want to acccess it into the Class B by using the delegate and event.. with passing the argument strings...

Comment: Did you know that you can edit your question to improve it? That's better than posting additinal comments.

Comment: now I corrected some part of question.please take a look

Comment: I would have expected that the backend class published the logging event and the GUI class subscribes to it. As it is written now (publish and subscribe in the same class) does not seem to make sense to me.

Comment: can you please give your proper suggestion if you had made some sense of the code

Answer (score 0):

I understood the background of your question as follows: the backend class publishes a logging event where it reports its progress or other information without having to know how this is displayed. The GUI class subscribes to this event and does whatever is appropriate. So something like this (only a sketch!):

```
public delegate void LoggingDelegate(string str);

public partial class Gui : Form
{
    public void ShowLog(string status)
    {
        try
        {
            if (richtxtBxResult.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action<string>(ShowLog), status);
            }
            else
            {
                richtxtBxResult.Text += Environment.NewLine + status;
                richtxtBxResult.SelectionStart = richtxtBxResult.Text.Length;
                richtxtBxResult.ScrollToCaret();
                richtxtBxResult.Refresh();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Program.WriteExceptionLog(ex);
        }
    }

    public void RunBackend()
    {
        var backend = new BackendClass();
        backend.LoggingEvent += ShowLog;
        Task.Run(() => backend.SomeAction());
    }
}

public class BackendClass
{
    public event LoggingDelegate LoggingEvent;

    public void SomeAction()
    {
        // ...
        LoggingEvent?.Invoke("Log output");
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou.It has much clear than before but the line Task.Run(()=> backend.SomeAction()); is not clear..Please...

Comment: This was just an example as I don't know what your backend class is and how it shall be invoked. Do anything suitable instead .

Comment: ok lets leave it for a short. Here you can see a if condition for InvokRequire. I want to get true it, and for that what i explored so far declare a thread for event. but it still not get ture even I created new parameterized thread.           LinuxScriptRunner lsr = new LinuxScriptRunner() //GUI class obj in backend class,
 lsr.MyEvent += new MyDel(lsr.ShowLog)///event initialize,
  System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(lsr.pqr));///thread for pqr() method having event invoke in GUI,
 t1.IsBackground = true,
 t1.Start("hi").